# How to integrate botfather telegram bot

Tags: python, async-await, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to integrate Telegram using BotFather and python-telegram-bot library

I have added a bot to my telegram channel and created it's key and named my channel as 'automated_alerts' but I am getting below warning and no messages being delivered

**Warning: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Bot.send_message' was never awaited**

```
import telegram

bot = telegram.Bot(token='####')
channel_id = 'automated_alerts'

bot.sendMessage(channel_id,"test")
```

Comment: As the error says, did you try `await bot.sendMessage(channel_id,"test")`?

Comment: I got the issue, it was due to channel id as I was taking channel name as id but it was a negative numeric number